# Python error after loading .pkl file "ValueError: Did not recognise loaded array layout"

Tags: python, python-2.7, svm

The code below is used for the training process of isolation forest in order to create a .pkl file (You can see the link here scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/…). After generating the .pkl file, I am to load it from ubuntu to raspbian OS. However, I encountered this error "ValueError: Did not recognise loaded array layout". Can anyone help me with this?
Complete error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "oneclass_test.py", line 24, in 
>    clf_one,stdSlr,voc,k = joblib.load('oneclass.pkl')
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 575, in
>    load obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 507, in
>    _unpickle obj = unpickler.load()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in
>    load dispatchkey
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 327, in
>    load_build Unpickler.load_build(self)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1217, in
>    load_build setstate(state)
>   File "sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx", line 650, in
>    sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.**setstate** (sklearn/tree/_tree.c:8406)
>   ValueError: Did not recognise loaded array layout

oneclass_train.py:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import argparse as ap
# Importing library that supports user friendly commandline interfaces
import cv2
# Importing the opencv library
import imutils
# Importing the library that supports basic image processing functions
import numpy as np
# Importing the array operations library for python
import os
# Importing the library which supports standard systems commands
from scipy.cluster.vq import *
# Importing the library which classifies set of observations into clusters
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

clf_one,stdSlr, voc,k = joblib.load("oneclass.pkl")

# Get the path of the testing set
parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument("-t", "--testingSet", help="Path to testing Set")
group.add_argument("-i", "--image", help="Path to image")
parser.add_argument('-v',"--visualize", action='store_true')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

# Get the path of the testing image(s) and store them in a list
image_paths = []
if args["testingSet"]:
    test_path = args["testingSet"]
    try:
        testing_names = os.listdir(test_path)
    except OSError:
        print "No such directory {}\nCheck if the file      exists".format(test_path)
        exit()
    for testing_name in testing_names:
        dir = os.path.join(test_path, testing_name)
        class_path = imutils.imlist(dir)
        image_paths+=class_path
else:
    image_paths = [args["image"]]

# Create feature extraction and keypoint detector objects
fea_det = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
des_ext = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# List where all the descriptors are stored
des_list = []
for image_path in image_paths:
    im = cv2.imread(image_path)
    r = 960.0 / im.shape[1]
    dim = (960, int(im.shape[0]*r))
    im = cv2.resize(im, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    if im == None:
        print "No such file {}\nCheck if the file exists".format(image_path)
        exit()
    img=im
    img2=im
    s = 75
    mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
    bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
    fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
    rect = (s,s,im.shape[1]-(2*s),im.shape[0]-(2*s)) cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,1,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
    mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
    im = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
    cv2.imwrite(image_path + "_Segment.jpg" ,im)
    print im.shape
    cv2.namedWindow("segmentation", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    pt = (0, 3 * im.shape[0] // 4)
    cv2.putText(im, "segmentation", pt ,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, 3, [0, 255, 0], 5)
    cv2.imshow("segmentation", im)
    cv2.waitKey(2000)
    kpts = fea_det.detect(im)  # Computing the key points of test image
    kpts, des = des_ext.compute(im, kpts)  # Computing the descriptors of the test image
    des_list.append((image_path, des))   # Appending the descriptors to a single list

# Stack all the descriptors vertically in a numpy array
descriptors = des_list[0][1]
for image_path, descriptor in des_list[0:]:
    descriptors = np.vstack((descriptors, descriptor))   # Stacking the descriptors in to a numpy array

# Computing the histogram of features
test_features = np.zeros((len(image_paths), k), "float32")
for i in xrange(len(image_paths)):
    words, distance = vq(des_list[i][1],voc)
    for w in words:
        test_features[i][w] += 1  # Calculating the histogram of features

# Perform Tf-Idf vectorization
nbr_occurences = np.sum( (test_features > 0) * 1, axis = 0)  # Getting the number of occurrences of each word
idf = np.array(np.log((1.0*len(image_paths)+1) / (1.0*nbr_occurences + 1)), 'float32')
# Assigning weight to one that is occurring more frequently

test_features = stdSlr.transform(test_features)

predictions = []
confidences = []

predictions = []
pred = clf_one.predict(test_features)
print clf_one.predict(test_features)
for i in pred:
    if i == 1:
            predictions += ["PPB"]
        if i == -1:
            predictions += ["NOT PPB"]

a=0
# Visualize the results, if "visualize" flag set to true by the user
if args["visualize"]:
    for image_path, prediction in zip(image_paths, predictions):
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        cv2.namedWindow(str(image_path), cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        pt = (0, 3 * image.shape[0] // 4)
        cv2.putText(image, prediction , pt ,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, 5, [0, 255, 0], 5)
        cv2.imshow(str(image_path), image)
        cv2.imwrite(image_path + "_oneclass_Result.jpg" ,image)
        cv2.waitKey(3000)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        a= a + 1
```

Comment: Sorry this is my first time to post. The code above is used for the training process of isolation forest in order to create a .pkl file (You can see the link here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html). I am loading the .pkl file from ubuntu to raspbian OS. After running the code I encountered the error given above.

Comment: Do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit the question. Do you know the protocol version used in `the .pkl file from ubuntu`? Your question is tagged `python-2.7`, which wouldn't unpickle version 3 (don't know about the error message).

Comment: @greybeard i already edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try matching the versions of the libraries used in both raspbian and ubuntu

Comment: I matched the version of sklearn on my raspberry pi (running Raspbian Jessie) and desktop system (running Ubuntu 16.04). sklearn version on both the machine is '0.18.1'. Even I matched the version of numpy, scipy, pandas also. But still I am getting same error: "Did not recognize loaded array layout" when I am trying to load model.pkl file, trained on Ubuntu desktop system to Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie). Please let me know about what else I can try...Thanks...